# How to place my App Icon into an iOS alert window

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller, appicon

I want to place my app icon into an alert controller above the alertTitle - same as for the alert that opens if an app review is called by `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()`.

I have not found any documentation about it.

So, what to do with the code below to let the App Icon appear?

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: alertHeaderText, message: alertText, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)


let option1: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "text", style: .default, handler: {
            (action) in

            // some code

        })

let option2: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "text", style: .default, handler: {
            (action) in

            // some code 

        })


alertController.addAction(option1)
alertController.addAction(option2)


self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I don’t think this is possible... I think you have to build a fully custom UI to do this.

Comment: I guess you should create a custom alert , see more : https://medium.com/if-let-swift-programming/design-and-code-your-own-uialertview-ec3d8c000f0a

Comment: but check it too , probably it works for you : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-alert-controller-in-ios-10-swift-3--cms-27589

Comment: Thanks for this link. I will try in the future...